# Javascript getDate() showing 1 more than expected (ex. showing 7 days instead of 6)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I am using javascript to write commands for a discord bot.  This command is used to see your "coins" associated with your username/ID and redeem a coin amount daily and weekly.  If you have already redeemed your coins for the day/week it shows a message giving you the time until the next redeem is possible.  That amount of time is derived from this equation:

```
var timeInt = oneWeek - (dateNow - gambler.weeklyDate);
var dateDif = new Date(timeInt);
```

oneWeek is the constant for number of milliseconds in one week (604800000), dateNow is the current date as an integer of milliseconds and gambler.weeklyDate is the date of the last redeem stored as an integer of milliseconds.

```
var nextRedeem =
     dateDif.getUTCDate() +
     ":" +
     dateDif.getUTCHours() +
     ":" +
     dateDif.getMinutes() +
     ":" +
     dateDif.getSeconds();
```

When I display the time formatted as days:hours:minutes:seconds using .getDate() or .getUTCDate() and create a string with the values the days value is always 1 higher that it should be.

I believe all of the values are correct and it should display as 6:23:59:59 if the command is run again 1 second after redeeming, but it displays as 7:23:59:59 which is incorrect.  Any fix for this?

Comment: May you provide a [mcve]? At the moment lots of variables are not defined in the question.

Comment: @evolutionxbox All variables being used have been defined in the description under the first code block and nextRedeem is just a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JS `Date()` type is not really suitable for representing intervals. Creating a `new Date()` from a number will always result in a actual timestamp and not an interval. In your special case the resulting date will most probably be a timestamp between 1970-01-01T00:00 and 1970-01-07T23:59:59. Of course you may interpret that date as a time interval, but then you'll have to substract 1 from your date, because `getDate()` returns the date within a month and months start with day 1 and not 0

If you know the next redeem will be allowed in `nextredeem` milliseconds you can easily get the correct number of days, hours, minutes, ... by division and modulo operations

```
let nextreedeem = ....;  //number of millisecons till next redeem

let days = Math.floor(nextreedem / 86400000);  
nextredeem = nextredem % 86400000;
let hours = Math.floor(nextredeem / 3600000);
nextredeem = nextredeem % 3600000;
let minutes = Math.floor(nextredeem / 60000);
nextredeem = nextredeem % 60000;
let seconds = Math.floor(nextredeem / 1000);
let milliseconds = nextredeem % 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

getUTCDate returns the day of the month, which will be between 1 and 31.  It'll work for your purposes, but because it can't return 0, you need to always subtract one to use it how you've designed.

Comment: Is there a function for a Date object that will return the proper day I am looking for? Or is subtracting 1 the only solution here?

Comment: @h8b1t The proper solution is not misusing the Date() object for representing intervals.

Comment: @derpirscher Please explain how I am misusing the Date() object in this context?  I am creating a new date object using a millisecond value which is a valid way to create a Date() object. Calling date.getDate() may be wrong here, that is why I am asking the question.

Comment: @h8b1t  Imagine a situation where the lastredeem was more than a week ago. Then your `timeInt` will get negative, thus the result of `new Date(timeInt)` will become for instance something like `1969-12-30T12:34:56`

Comment: @derpirscher Yes, I see what you mean now.  I have this code inside an if() block that checks if the time elapsed has been less than one week.  Thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

`getUTCdate()` only checks the day of the month. Witch means that if one date is Saturday ad 14:00, and the the other is the next Saturday at 13:59, the difference will still be 7 days, and not 6 days, 23 hours...etc.

A possible solution is to calculate the days yourself starting from the total of milliseconds:

```
const days = Math.floor(dateDif / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Just subtracting 1 from `getUTCDate()` wont work correctly. If the difference between `oneWeek` and `(dateNow - gambler.weeklyDate)` is less than 24 hours, chances are that they will be on the same day, so the difference would be 0, and if you subtract 1 you get -1.